# Adding to check in if-else block in Python

Tags: python

I have the following code;

```
if A:
    X = find()
else:
    X = find(all=True)
```

I need to add a new check - if `C` then `find(amonut=C)`.
In other words, the code would look like:

```
if A:
    if C:
         X = find(amount=C)
    else:
         X = find()
elif C:
    X = find(amount=C)
else:
    X = find(all=True)
```

It looks very ugly. Is there a better way to achieve the same behavior?

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me that you find by amount "when `C`" irrespective of what `A` is, so make that the first thing to think about.  Plus you can use `elif` to avoid deep nesting in this case:

```
if C:
     x = find(amount=C)
elif A:
     x = find()
else:
     x = find(all=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if A and not C:
    X = find()
elif C:
    X = find(amount=C)
else:
    X = find(all=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Single line if/else

```
X = find(amount=C) if C else find() if A else find(all=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Switcher instead of a bunch of if statements.

[learn more about switcher](https://jaxenter.com/implement-switch-case-statement-python-138315.html)

Comment: Providing the code demonstrating how it would be used for this case would improve this answer.

Comment: @Dave I agree with you. but in general, if statements could be converted to switcher only if they are trying to compare one argument with different values.